# Convert SQL sentence to LINQ

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq

I need to create a LINQ sentence that does the same as this SQL sentence but I can't solve it...

```
SELECT l.Id, l.Url, t.Name, t.LanguageCode
FROM link l 
LEFT OUTER JOIN linktr t ON t.Id = (SELECT tt.Id FROM linktr tt WHERE tt.LinkId = l.Id AND (tt.LanguageCode = 'en-EN' OR tt.LanguageCode = 'es-ES') ORDER BY (tt.LanguageCode = 'en-EN') DESC, tt.LanguageCode LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY l.OrderPos

Table Link
Id, Url

Table LinkTr
Id, LinkId, Name, LanguageCode
```

The table link contains the Url of the link while the LinkTr contains the name and it can cointain multiple languages

I want to select all the links we have in the links database and for each link I want to show JUST ONE language, the one that corresponds to the current language if exists, but if it doesn't exist I have to show the one that corresponds to the default language. If no one of them exist it wouldn't show that record.

For this example the default language is es-ES and the current one is en-EN.

How can I do this using LINQ?

Thanks in advance

EDIT

If I use this LINQ expression it works only if I comment the ORDER line, but without the ORDER line (.OrderBy(p3 => p3.LanguageCode == currentLanguage)) it takes the first record in the db by Id, but not the current language first.

```
var queryString = from i in _dbContext.Links
let p = _dbContext.LinksTrs.Where(p2 => i.Id == p2.LinkId && (p2.LanguageCode == currentLanguage || p2.LanguageCode == defaultLanguage))
.OrderBy(p3 => p3.LanguageCode == currentLanguage)
.FirstOrDefault()
orderby i.OrderPos
select new LinksWebListModel
{
   Id = i.Id,
   Name = (p == null) ? "" : p.Name,
   Url = i.Url,
   Summary = (p == null) ? "" : p.Summary,
};
```

EDIT 2

I'm suing EF6 and my entities, which I can't change, are these:

```
public class Link : EntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrderPos { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<LinkTr> Translations { get; set; }
}

public class LinkTr
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LanguageCode { get; set; }

    public int LinkId { get; set; }
    public virtual Link Link { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT 3

it would be something like this...

```
var queryString = (from entity in _dbContext.Links
                                let translation = _dbContext.LinksTrs
                                            .Where(p2 => p2.LinkId == entity.Id)
                                            .Where(p3 => p3.LanguageCode == currentLanguage || p3.LanguageCode == defaultLanguage)
                                            .OrderBy(p4 => p4.LanguageCode)
                                            .FirstOrDefault()
                               orderby entity.OrderPos descending
                               select new LinksWebListModel()
                               {
                                   Id = entity.Id,
                                   Name = translation.Name,
                                   Url = entity.Url,
                                   Summary = translation.Summary,
                               });
```

buit the problems here are 2:
- I need to return the record (Links) only if there is a row in the sub query (LinksTrs)
- Also I'd need to order the subquery by "currentLanguage" first and then "defaultLanguage" and then the rest. If I add this to the sub query I get an error:

```
.OrderBy(p4 => p4.LanguageCode == currentLanguage)
.ThenBy(p5 => p5.LanguageCode == defaultLanguage)
.ThenBy(p6 => p6.LanguageCode)
```

Do you have an idea on how to order by certain values, for example if I have these languages "es-ES", "en-EN", "it-IT", "fr-FR" for example to get first "it-IT", then "es-ES" and then order by name...

Comment: Just to be clear - do you "need" a LINQ query that will be translated to an equivalent SQL statement, or do you "need" a Linq statement that will be the equivalent of that SQL against a collection of objects?

Comment: I need a LINQ query thet will be the equivalent of the given SQL query

Comment: Try downloading [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/). [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) is another invaluable resource, it won't generate the LINQ for you but it does a provide a scratchpad that can be used to display the SQL generated from a LINQ statement, so you can keep messing about with it until you get the SQL statement you're after.